# Passing column names in stored procedure in java and sql server?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on JSP application and I am really stuck at this point. The DB Admin has given me a stored procedure and he wants me to pass column names corresponding to values in the stored procedure. I asked him if i can pass index value in the prepared statement and not column name but then he said me that it can be a major issue if I use index value. So, please please suggest me a way so that I can pass column name in the prepared statement and not index value.

e.g - Currently say my procedure is called

```
 mystmt = conn.preparestatement("exec p_addeditcustomer ?,?,?");
   mystmt.setString(1,"A");
   mystmt.setString(2,"B");
   mystmt.setString(3,"C");
```

Now, my db admin wants me to pass such as

```
mystmt.setString("@CustomerName","A");
mystmt.setString("@CustomertTitle","B");
mystmt.setString("@CustomerCountry","C");
```

Please tell me how I can do that. I am really clueless.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), this is meant to be used with stored procedures :

```
  CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call p_addeditcustomer(?,?,?)}");

  cstmt.setString("CustomerName", "A");
  cstmt.setString("CustomertTitle", "B");
  cstmt.setString("CustomerCountry", "C");
```

Comment: :- Will callablestatement work with SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: @Farheen : Yes it should also work with SQL Server, you may find additional examples here : https://programmaticponderings.com/2012/08/24/calling-sql-server-stored-procedures-with-java-using-jdbc/ .

Comment: @Farheen its the other way around. JDBC is a standardized API, database vendors provide drivers which implement it. So yes, SQL Server supports CallableStatement.